# Is there an easier way to access attributes of a class in R, can I use dot notation?

Tags: r, object, attributes

I have created an object in R that contains several attributes. How can I easily access them?

I can do:

```
attr(x, attributeName)
```

or:

```
attributes(x)$attributeName
```

but none of them is really convenient.

Is there a quicker way (like the dot in C++ or Java)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use attributes for your object, use a list:

```
myobj <- structure(list(a = 1, b = 2), class = "myclass")
print.myclass <- function(x, ...) cat("A: ", x$a, " B: ", x$b, "\n", sep = "")
myobj
```

Of course, this might not work if you're extending an existing object (e.g. vector), but in my experience it's a generally better way to build objects.

Comment: The question is how to access attributes. Your answer is "don't do that" which is not an answer to the question that was asked. There are other people who are searching for answers to the same question.

Comment: I agree, what if a function returns an object with attributes? This is the answer that comes up.

Comment: ^ I think his point is that a 'correct' answer to this question doesn't exist, so he is giving a reasonable workaround. It is a good answer to the question, if you're already given attributes to work with then just use `attr(x, 'y')`

Answer (score 27):

`attributes()` returns a named list. I'd call it once and store them, then access via names. There is no point repeatedly calling either `attr()` or `attributes()` if you don't have to.

```
x <- 1:10
attr(x, "foo") <- "a"
attr(x, "bar") <- "b"
(features <- attributes(x))
```

which gives:

```
R> (features <- attributes(x))
$foo
[1] "a"

$bar
[1] "b"
```

then access in the usual way

```
R> features["foo"]
$foo
[1] "a"

R> features$foo
[1] "a"
```

Answer (score 11):

probably there is no built-in function that is counter part of . in C++, but you can define it like this:

```
> `%.%` <- function(o, a) attr(o, as.character(substitute(a)))
> x <- 1
> attr(x, "orz") <- 2
> x%.%orz
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I am now looking at S4 classes that allo object@attr

Comment: Choosing a class system based on how attributes/fields/slots are accessed is probably not the best way to make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

Example of using the match.length attribute that is returned from regexpr:

Three strings in a vector, first and third include an embedded string:

```
data=c("<a href=\"ch4.html\">Chapter 1</a>",
       "no quoted string is embedded in this string",
       "<a   href=\"appendix.html\">Appendix</a>")
```

Use regexpr to locate the embedded strings:

```
> locations <- regexpr("\"(.*?)\"", data)
```

Matches are in the first string (at 9 with length 10) and third string (at 11 with length 15):

```
> locations
[1]  9 -1 11
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 10 -1 15
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Vector from the attribute:

```
> attr(locations,"match.length")
[1] 10 -1 15
```

Use substr and the attribute vector to extract the strings:

```
> quoted_strings=substr( data, 
                         locations, 
                         locations+attr(locations,"match.length")-1 )    
> quoted_strings
[1] "\"ch4.html\""      ""                  "\"appendix.html\""
```

Maybe you'd like to remove the embedded quote characters from your strings:

```
> gsub("\"", "", quoted_strings)
[1] "ch4.html"      ""              "appendix.html"
```

An alternative is to use regmatches:

```
> regmatches(data,locations)
[1] "\"ch4.html\""      "\"appendix.html\""
```