getting the list of "attributes" in an R object
in R when accessing a slot we can do x@a to access the slot "a" from object x. we can get the list of slots with slotNames, how do you get the set of "elements" that one would access with the '$' operator by using a function like slotNames?
I tried names(x) and it works for lists, but not for other classes, also attributes returns slots, but I don't want this.
One example (not reproducible) is:
I have an object x of class DimReduc (Seurat). When I do names(x) it lists many names: Integrated_1, Integrated_2, ...., many times.
When I try and access using the '$' (x$) I get a list of different values. When I say slotNames(x), I get a different list. this is while editing code. But I want to get the list of possible values during runtime as if I were to type x$. clearly there's a way to define names() separate of $. note this is not a dataframe.
thanks

This looks like a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449565/is-there-an-easier-way-to-access-attributes-of-a-class-in-r-can-i-use-dot-notat

"also attributes returns slots, but I don't want this" It is unclear what exactly you are asking if names(x) and names(attributes(x)) are not the answer.

No duplicate, attributes() is not good in my case.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

There is no $ method for DimReduc objects. You can't use this extractor with such an object so your description is incomplete. You need to make your question much more specific, you are clearly not asking about arbitrary R objects but specific S4 objects.

Try attributes(x) to list them, and once you have an attribute name, say 'abc', use attr(x, "abc") to access it.  This works on S3 objects, what you described for slots is specific to S4 objects.
An example: after running example(ts) to set up timeseries object, you can inspect the last ts object created via
> attributes(nhtemp)
$tsp
[1] 1912 1971    1

$class
[1] "ts"

> 

which reveals both the S3 class (ts) and the attributes defining this time series to be annual from 1912 to 1971.
